# What is the best storage for data without relations

Tags: java, spring, database, web, storage

I am developing a simple web application based on Spring Boot, which needs only one table (four columns inside) of data without any relationships. So the data model is very light, but still, it has to be store in someplace and cannot disappear after the application reset.

Table (or some collection of data) includes objects, where every object has three one-word strings as separated properties and one boolean property. Two strings are immutable (name and surname). During the application life, probably only the boolean field will be changed in objects. This change will be scheduled and executed once a week.

I do not need transactions, and also application is not multi-threaded. It is Java-only application. Queries will be executed only from scheduled task. Size of data collection will be keeping at the same level. It also is going to be very internal application, so we do not have to keep notice about some problems which appear in big infrastructures.

Which type of storage should I use in this case? Some NoSQL databases like Mongo? Or maybe keep this data inside some file stored on the server-side and read/write to it?

Comment: A lot of important details are missing from the question.  As it stands, there are many possible ways to do this .... and we cannot narrow it down to a single or small number of "best" options.

Comment: Okay, I will describe some more details in question.

Comment: Things like: do you need transactions?  ACID?  Is the data shared between different instances of the application?  Is this a Java-only application?  Is the application multi-threaded?  (E.g. a web server.)  How do you query it?  (Iterating the records?  Looking up records by key?  Some other way?)  How much data?  Will the schema evolve / grow?  And a few more that I can't think of right now.

Comment: So let me answer your questions:
I do not need transactions, and also application is not multithreaded. It is Java-only application. Queries will be executed only from scheduled task. Size of data collection will be keeping at the same level. It also is going to be veeery internal application, so we do not have to keep notice about some problems which appear in big infrastructures.

Comment: Put the details in your Question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you plan to search thru it?

If NO then a flat file is the solution.

if YES you will need to index it. So better use DB for that.
Any DB would do!

Advantage with **mongo** is that one can change the schema on the fly, so perhaps a decent choice in your case.
Just remember to index the collection!

Comment: I am sure that I will not keep in this storage a lot of records. The case which this application is going to handle needs to store max 20 records and no more for sure.

Basing on your answer I probably will choose file storage, because searching thru this data won't be problematicaly.

Comment: yes for 20 items - you load the text into memory, keep it in memory for save/load and form time to time save it to disk (either periodically or onChange - whichever makes sense)

Comment: do you have any suggestions or tips which file type will be the best for store data? I can tell you, that each object has four fields - three of them are Strings, and one is boolean. I thought about txt file, where every object's property will be splitted by space char. But maybe better choise will be json? What do you think about it?

Comment: hey! from one column .. now we have 4? :)

Comment: depends of the values of the string fields... if any of those can have the separator character (space or ,) it wont work - with json you are always save.

Comment: Ahhh, my bad - in question I meant "one table" instead "column". I will repair my mistake immediately. So I have one table ( :) ) which contains four columns, three one-word strings, and one boolean value.
Json looks more comoftable for me, because with splitting text by e.g. I will be forced to make a lot of null checks and if statements to check splitted strings array size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219380/discussion-between-deian-and-travelervihaan).